# Passing GpuMat directly to cufftExecC2C function for doing fast fourier transform

Tags: opencv, cuda, cufft

I am trying to optimize my code using opencv with cuda and cufft library. Everytime I have do fast fourier transform, I have to download cv::Mat from GpuMat and then do cufft. (Please see the code below) and again download the result of the fft. Is there any way I can optimize this ? I wanted to know if there is any way I could directly pass GpuMat without having to download it.

```
std::vector<cv::cuda::GpuMat> ReconClass::FFT2(std::vector<cv::cuda::GpuMat>& mat, int height, int width)
{
    cufftHandle plan;
    cufftComplex* data, * datao, * devdata, * devdatao;

    size_t arraySize = sizeof(cufftComplex) * mat[0].size().area();
    cudaMallocHost((void**)& data, arraySize);
    cudaMallocHost((void**)& datao, arraySize);

    cudaMalloc((void**)& devdata, arraySize);
    cudaMalloc((void**)& devdatao, arraySize);

    cv::Mat iReal;
    cv::Mat iImag;
    mat[0].download(iReal);
    mat[1].download(iImag);

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            data[i * width + j].x = iReal.at<float>(i, j);
            data[i * width + j].y = iImag.at<float>(i, j);
        }
    }
    cudaMemcpy(devdata, data, arraySize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    cufftPlan2d(&plan, height, width, CUFFT_C2C);

    if (!plan)
        std::cout << "the cufftPlan2d plan returned is null" << std::endl;

    cufftExecC2C(plan, (cufftComplex*)devdata, (cufftComplex*)devdatao, CUFFT_FORWARD);

    cudaMemcpy(datao, devdatao, arraySize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cv::Mat realRecon(height, width, CV_32F);
    cv::Mat imagRecon(height, width, CV_32F);

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            realRecon.at<float>(i, j) = datao[i * width + j].x;
            imagRecon.at<float>(i, j) = datao[i * width + j].y;
        }
    }

    cv::cuda::GpuMat mat1, mat2;
    mat1.upload(realRecon);
    mat2.upload(imagRecon);

    std::vector<cv::cuda::GpuMat> re = { mat1 , mat2 };

    cufftDestroy(plan);
    cudaFreeHost(data);
    cudaFreeHost(datao);
    cudaFree(devdata);
    cudaFree(devdatao);

    return re;
}
```

Comment: mat[0] -> real values & mat[1] -> Imag values

Comment: There is no avoiding the necessity of reordering the data for the fft call. But you could easily write a kernel to perform the transformation on the device.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I was able to avoid copy to the CPU and back copy to the device. Also doing inplace FFT helped improve performance. I have pasted my code below.

```
void Dataransfer2Cuda(const cv::InputArray _dReal, const cv::InputArray _dImag, float2* zCufftcomplex)
{
    const cv::cuda::GpuMat Real = _dReal.getGpuMat();
    const cv::cuda::GpuMat Imag = _dImag.getGpuMat();

    dim3 cthreads(32, 32);
    dim3 cblocks(
        static_cast<int>(std::ceil(Real.size().width /
            static_cast<double>(cthreads.x))),
        static_cast<int>(std::ceil(Real.size().height /
            static_cast<double>(cthreads.y))));

    Kernel_DataTransfer2Cuda << <cblocks, cthreads >> > (Real, Imag, zCufftcomplex);

    if (cudaSuccess != cudaGetLastError())
        std::cout << "Dataransfer2Cuda(): gave an error" << std::endl;

    return;
}

void DataransferFromCuda(const float2* zCufftcomplex, cv::OutputArray _outputReal, cv::OutputArray _outputImag, std::size_t iWidth, std::size_t iHeight)
{

    _outputReal.create(iHeight, iWidth, CV_32F);
    _outputImag.create(iHeight, iWidth, CV_32F);

    cv::cuda::GpuMat outputReal = _outputReal.getGpuMat();
    cv::cuda::GpuMat outputImag = _outputImag.getGpuMat();


    dim3 cthreads(32, 32);
    dim3 cblocks(
        static_cast<int>(std::ceil(outputReal.size().width /
            static_cast<double>(cthreads.x))),
        static_cast<int>(std::ceil(outputReal.size().height /
            static_cast<double>(cthreads.y))));

    Kernel_DataTransferFromCuda << <cblocks, cthreads >> > (zCufftcomplex, outputReal, outputImag);

    if (cudaSuccess != cudaGetLastError())
        std::cout << "DataransferFromCuda(): gave an error" << std::endl;

    return;
}

std::vector<cv::cuda::GpuMat> ReconClass::FFT2(std::vector<cv::cuda::GpuMat>& mat, int height, int width)
{
    cufftHandle plan;
    cufftComplex* devdata;

    size_t arraySize = sizeof(cufftComplex) * mat[0].size().area();

    cudaMalloc((void**)& devdata, arraySize);

    Dataransfer2Cuda(mat[0], mat[1], devdata);

    cufftPlan2d(&plan, height, width, CUFFT_C2C);

    if (!plan)
        std::cout << "the cufftPlan2d plan returned is null" << std::endl;

    cufftExecC2C(plan, (cufftComplex*)devdata, (cufftComplex*)devdata, CUFFT_FORWARD);

    cv::cuda::GpuMat mat1, mat2;
    DataransferFromCuda(devdata, mat1, mat2, width, height);
    std::vector<cv::cuda::GpuMat> re = { mat1 , mat2 };

    cufftDestroy(plan);
    cudaFree(devdata);

    return re;
}
```

Comment: You forgot the kernel definitions; they should be trivial, but it'd be good to include them for completeness